# website not resizing correctly in mobile

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

So I am working on an assignment, and in full screen on the desktop it looks fine. However in mobile the top o fthe page background doesn't extend right, the middle section is not centered, and the bottom section does not extend right. Also when I shrink the page in my browser the text in the top third gets cut off rather than scaling. I am at a bit of a loss and am hoping for some sort of guidance. I am new to web applications. I have included the code as well as links to the page and my repository oif the code
    https://profile-josh-adams.herokuapp.com/
    https://github.com/ender554/profile

HTML

```
  <head>
    <title>Josh Adams</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#index-page">Josh Adams</a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#index-page">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#resume-page">Resume<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#links-page">Links</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="mailto:joshadams554@gmail.com">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  <div class="index container-fluid" id="index-page">
    <div class="headline">About Me</div>
    <hr>

    <div class="media col-8 offset-2">
      <span class="media-left">
        <%= image_tag("profilephoto.jpg") %>
      </span>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h2 class="media-heading">Joshua Adams:</h2>
        <hr class="title-rule">
        <h3 class="about-body">
      I am a 37 year old student with an extreme eagerness to learn, and be 
<br /><br />a key contributor in any profession. I love the academic setting and 
<br /><br />the skills it has helped me build, but I understand that in this field it is
<br /><br /> most important to learn in a real world environment, and I hope to 
<br /><br />extend my abilities greatly.
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="resume col-6 offset-3" id="resume-page">
    <h1 class="resume">Resume:</h1>
    <div class="resume-itself">
      <%= image_tag("resume.jpg") %>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="links" id="links-page">
    <h1 class="links-title">Links:</h1>
    <div class="actual-links col-8 offset-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <%= link_to image_tag("linkedin.png"), "https://www.linkedin.com/in/joshua-adams-061901b6/", :target => "_blank" %>

        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <%= image_tag("piazza.png") %>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <%= link_to image_tag("github.jpg"), "https://github.com/ender554", :target => "_blank" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@import "bootstrap";

body {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
}

#index-page {
  background: image_url('indexbackground.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}


h1 {
  color: white;
}

.media {
  margin-top: 50px;
}



.headline {
  font-size: 80pt;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: 'chunkfiveroman'; 
}

hr {
  width: 75%; 
  color: black; 
  height: 2px; 
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.title-rule {
  width: 95%; 
  color: black; 
  height: 2px; 
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.media-heading {
  margin-left: 25px;
  color: white;

}
.index {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}

.about-body{
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: white;  
}

.resume {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: Black;
  font-size: 50pt;
  padding-top: 20px;


}
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:1;
}

.media-left img{
  border-radius: 5%;
  border: solid white 2px;
}

.links {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: Black;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 50pt;
  height: 1000px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.links-title {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  font-size: 80pt;
  padding-top: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add this two lines in your head tag, this will fixed your responsive issue

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

last line is for responsive purpose

you have one more css issue your image is too large

apply below css and it will take care of it

```
.resume-itself img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: that worked for the center section, however the top and bottom section both got much smaller and teh words on the top are no longer visable

Answer (score 0):

use proper classes which bootstrap provided. you are using bootstrap classes in wrong way

use this link to learn more about bootstrap
[bootstrap 3 tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you may need to add following lines inside  element.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Ex - .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```